# How to update Baobab leaf data before React component render?

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, flux, baobab

ReactJS, Baobab, Material-UI app displays some items, identified by their numeric id. To display those, title and image url's are retrieved from a remote service via ajax. Tree branch stores that data:

```
data: {
  12345: {title:'ABC', image:'https://...'}, // id is 12345
  12346: {...
}
```

Upon item component creation and first rendering, its extended data may, or may not be already available in the tree. If its not, ajax call is enqueued to receive that data. It might happen that multiple items are created with the same item id.

To avoid extra requests for the same id, I want to put a dummy info `{title:'loading', image:'spinner.gif'}` into the tree upon the first request to that id's info. Thus this data will be used for the very first `render()`. Successive components would get that dummy info, and will not initiate any extra requests.

**Question:** how, and where can I place the code to test if the tree has no info yet and place the dummy there to indicate its "penging" state and enqueue the request?

Tried so far:

- component's `constructor` – props are not set there yet;
- `componentWillMount()` – the first render started with the old state of the tree, despite the `tree.commit()` after setting the dummy value;
- in the branch function that dynamically creates components cursor pointing to its data. Got warning:

> setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.

This can be solved one level up – once the list of ids is available. But it feels right that a component should be able to handle its data within itself.

Please advice a correct way to immediately update Baobab tree data before the first render of a React Component, from within that Component?

Answer (score 1):

In my case (i am use same stack) wrap branch work fine.

```
import BaobabPropTypes  from 'baobab-react/prop-types';
class Actions {
    /**
     * @param {Baobab} tree
    */
    static prefetchTree = (tree) => {
        tree.select(somePath).set(defaultValue);
        tree.commit();
    };
}

class Page extends React.Component {
    static contextTypes = {
        tree: BaobabPropTypes.baobab
    };

    componentWillMount() {
        Actions.prefetchTree(this.context.tree);
    }

    render() {
        return <Branch {...this.props}/>;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I will recheck – the only diff with my setup is that you call `tree.update()` in another function (action), while I tested it right in `componentWillMount()` body. Meanwhile I rolled back to a prefetch in a parent component as it allows to group multiple ajax calls into one.

Comment: For each route i have a Page component (this is like layout) and call prefetch only in it. This prefetch  supplement values obtained from serverPrefetch (rendering on the server). In other words, I try to have only one prefetch, similar to the server on each route.
I think we are using similar solutions

Answer (score 0):

Baobab has a `get` event, use it to detect requests that return values that are not fetched yet:

```
tree.on('get', function(e) {
  if (e.data.data === undefined) {
     const path = e.data.path; // requested cursor path like ['data',12345]
     const id = path[1]; 
     FETCH_DATA(id)
        .then( data => tree.set(path , data) );
     tree.set(path, PLACEHOLDER_DATA);
  }
```